# Python 3.X pycomm.ab_comm.clx CommError: must be str, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x, plc, comm

Im trying to get "PYCOMM" to connect to my CLX 5000 processor.
Every time I run my code I get:**CommError: must be str, not bytes.**
I have looked all over the code and I cant find where the issue is. Everything that is supposed to be in a string format is.
I am using python3.6
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from pycomm.ab_comm.clx import Driver as ClxDriver


c = ClxDriver()


if c.open('172.16.2.161'):
    print(c.read_tag('Start'))
    # Prints (1,'BOOL') if true; (0,'BOOL') if false
    c.close()
```

Here is the error:

C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\python.exe C:/Users/shirley/Downloads/pycomm-pycomm3/pycomm-pycomm3/examples/test_clx_comm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pycomm\cip\cip_base.py", **line 617, in build_header
    h += pack_uint(length)                      # Length UINT
TypeError: must be str, not bytes**

```
    The header is 24 bytes fixed length, and includes the command and the length of the optional data portion.

     :return: the headre
    """
    try:
        h = command                                 # Command UINT
        **h += pack_uint(length)                      # Length UINT**
        h += pack_dint(self._session)                # Session Handle UDINT
        h += pack_dint(0)                           # Status UDINT
        h += self.attribs['context']                # Sender Context 8 bytes
        h += pack_dint(self.attribs['option'])      # Option UDINT
        return h
    except Exception as e:
        raise CommError(e)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pycomm\cip\cip_base.py", line 786, in open
    if self.register_session() is None:
  File "C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pycomm\cip\cip_base.py", line 635, in register_session
    self._message = self.build_header(ENCAPSULATION_COMMAND['register_session'], 4)
  File "C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pycomm\cip\cip_base.py", line 624, in build_header
    raise CommError(e)
**pycomm.cip.cip_base.CommError: must be str, not bytes**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shirley/Downloads/pycomm-pycomm3/pycomm-pycomm3/examples/test_clx_comm.py", line 5, in 
    if c.open('172.16.2.161'):
  File "C:\Users\shirley\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pycomm\cip\cip_base.py", line 793, in open
    raise CommError(e)
**pycomm.cip.cip_base.CommError: must be str, not bytes**

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against wall trying to figure this out on my own. 
I just switched to using PYLOGIX
https://github.com/dmroeder/pylogix
It worked the first time I ran it
and its reasonably fast.

Comment: A great solution if you are using a MicroLogix8XX or CLX driver based, but not a great solution for other SLC devices such as Micrologix 11XX or older SLC PLCs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

The error is because you are using Python 3.x, and I did the same thing: I used Python 3.6 instead of Python 2.6 or 2.7.

Change Python 3.x to 2.6 or 2.7 (I used 2.7).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that was fixed recently

I have it working with `pycomm@1.0.8` and `python@3.7.3`

Comment: How do we come by this fix? I'm running into this both using a pip install and after cloning and running setup in Python 3.6.3